# Convert swatch group to global swatches

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, swatches

Is there a way to create multiple global swatches with an existing swatch group? I have shift+clicked the swatches in the group and went to the group folder but the convert process to global tickbox is greyed out.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do this from a floating, independent, library panel.

You must add the swatches to the main **Swatches Panel** first. You can do that by simply clicking the Color Group Folder icon in the unique library panel.

[image]

Then in the main Swatches Panel highlight *only* the color swatches **not** the color group folder. And from the menu choose **Swatch Options**. (Note, if you have the *folder* also selected the menu will read "Color Group Options" and is *not* what you want.)

[image]

**Don't** highlight the little folder. Only highlight the swatches. You will then be able to set the swatches a global.

[image]

---

Most external swatch library files are in .ase format and can't be opened directly by AI - they can merely be loaded as a panel. The .ase format means they can also be loaded into Photoshop or InDesign as swatches!

[image]

But, if an external swatch library happens to be in .ai format, you can open that library file directly in Illustrator and then convert the swatches there to Global.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Save and close the file.

Then, in the future when you load the library, the swatches will be set as global in the floating panel.

[image]

To be honest, I don't really know why all the swatches that come with AI aren't already set as global. I mean, it makes life so much easier ultimately. I can only assume there's some sort of compatibility issue with the .ase format.